# How to get refresh token (google api), of the user?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have a scenario where user when get authorize to my app I do keep his/her `access_token` for the sake of later api call not exactly at the same time, but at later time when require.

I am successful in above thing, the issue is when that `access_token` get expired I want to refresh that `access_token`.

I am unsuccessful retrieving the `refresh_code` of the user account, Did try difference approaches, but no success.

So I am expecting a working solution for the case, I wan't user to get `signIn` in my application, perform authorization  and on authorization I want that `refresh_token`, but not receive.

Help in this regard will be really appreciated,

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: If you are using the google oauth api strictly for login (no google services used), you're overthinking the issue. You have to implement a token-based service yourself. You use oauth strictly to confirm the user is who they say they are. It's your responsibility after that to handle their session

Comment: @Andrew, no friend I have to use that for using google drive api :-), any help?